# Minizinc strange behaviour

Tags: minizinc

I have recently started studying minizinc, but I have got this strange behaviour in my program.

#### .dzn

```
n = 5;
c = 2;
```

##### .mzn

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n;
int: c;

set of int: num_deliveries = 1..n-1;
int: headquarter = 1;
set of int: num_places = 1..n;
set of int: deliveries = 2..n;
set of int: couriers = 1..c;
set of int: num_max_deliveries = 1..n+2;
set of int: schedule_domain = 0..n;
int: first_place_idx = 1;
int: last_place_idx = n+2;

array[couriers,num_max_deliveries] of var schedule_domain: schedule;
array[1..2*n] of int: total = [schedule[i,j]|i,j in num_max_deliveries where i<=2 /\ j != first_place_idx /\ j!= last_place_idx];
output ["len_without_variable = \(length([ k | k in total where k != 0]))"];
var int: len_cleaned = length([ k | k in total where k != 0]);

output ["len_with_variable = \(len_cleaned)\n"];
```

In particular, from these lines of code I have different results, even if they are equal.

```
output ["len_without_variable = \(length([ k | k in total where k != 0]))"];
var int: len_cleaned = length([ k | k in total where k != 0]);
output ["len_with_variable = \(len_cleaned)\n"];
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: It would help if you add the information that is missing in your code (to make it runnable), e.g. `schedule`, `num_max_deliveries`, `first_place_idx`. And also add the output so we can see the different results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one output of the model is this (with `total` added):

```
len_without_variable = 2
len_with_variable = 10
total: [3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if the two calculations of the number of non zero elements in `total` should be the same or not. Perhaps this is a bug in how `length` operates on decision variables (with a `where` condition), and it should be 2 (in this example). Until this is settled, you should probably avoid using `length` like this.

The output of `len_without_variable` - the one defined in the output section - operates on the actual and known values of the solution. So this might not be the exact thing as using `length` in a constraint/variable definition.

To calculate the number of non zero values you can use `sum` instead:

```
var 0..n num_non_zeros = sum([ 1 | k in total where k != 0]);
```

However, the construct `... where k != 0` creates temporary variables which makes the model larger than necessary so it's better to use the following:

```
var 0..n num_non_zeros = sum([ total[i] != 0 | i in 1..n]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @jordy If you think that it solves your problem, please accept it as a answer.